# Read variable from MainActivity.java in Flutter Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to disable logging of Firebase Analytics in a Flutter project when the app is being run on Firebase Test Lab. According to Firebase docs, TestLab can be detected by adding the following in MainActivity.java

```
String testLabSetting = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "firebase.test.lab");
if ("true".equals(testLabSetting)) {
    // Do something when running in Test Lab
    // ...
}
```

How can I access the result of this test on the dart side in main.dart which is where I want to disable logging (as there are some other reasons logging is disabled already in the dart code).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `MethodChannel` to send data (`boolean` here) to your Dart code.

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: @pskink It doesn't work

Comment: @pskink I tried to create a MethodChannel and checking "firebase.test.lab" but still the bots create accounts

Answer (score 4):

I just found this. I didn't try it yet though:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_runtime_env

> This project allows you to check if you're running in the Firebase
> Test Labs

You can use it like their example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_runtime_env/flutter_runtime_env.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _shouldBeEnabled = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    var result = await shouldEnableAnalytics();
    setState(() {
      _shouldBeEnabled = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Should Enable Analytics'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Should Analytics be Enabled: $_shouldBeEnabled\n'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I think I found a better solution.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sentry

It has the follow method

```
/// Return `true` if running under Firebase Test Lab (includes pre-launch
/// report environment) on Android, `false` otherwise.
static Future<bool> isFirebaseTestLab() async
```

It seems to be the best solution so far...

EDIT 2:

Fuck it! I just created a small plugin.

https://pub.dev/packages/is_firebase_test_lab_activated

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)